# php - fgets - read first line twice?

Tags: php, fgets

i have a while loop that FGETS through an external file and then executes function a() over each line.

what i want to do is to first look at the first line. if the line meets certain criteria, I want to execute function b() with it and then have the while loop work the a() function over lines 2+.

if the first line does NOT match the criteria, then i want the while loop to work the a() function over lines 1+.

is this possible without having to close and reopen the file again?

Comment: what do you mean by `lines 2+`, do you mean the next two lines?

Comment: i mean all lines starting from the second one up.

Comment: Wouldn't 2nd one up just be line 1 and 2? Do you mean 2nd, 3rd, 4th down to last line? That would be all the lines that have not been read yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you read first line you can reset file pointer to start of file, using [fseek](http://php.net/fseek)

```
fseek($file,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Here's one way:

```
if (($line = fgets(...)) !== false)
{
  if (meets_criteria($line))
  {
    b($line);
  }
  else
  {
    a($line);
  };
  while (($line = fgets(...)) !== false)
  {
    a($line);
  };
};
```

Feel free to fix any errors found.

Comment: that's good thinking, wow.
i went with the fseek answer below before i had a chance to look at your version.
now i'm torn :)))

Comment: My answer does violate [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but it also works on streams.

Answer (score -1):

If the file is not too big to be read into memory, you can just use `file()` instead of FGETS like this

```
$lines = file('the-data.file');
foreach($lines as $line){
 if (meets_criteria($line))
  {
    b($line);
    a(implode(array_slice($lines,2)));
  }
  else
  {
    a(implode($lines));
  };
};
```